# What a user can see vs what they can do

Tags: sql-server, ssms

MSSQL allows a user with limited permissions on a database to navigate using SSMS on that database as if they were an admin. I.e. if they have view permission on a database they can look at users, all options to grant/deny are selectable, but of course nothing is committed to the database.

I heard a user boasting about their level of access, which I had set and limited, but had a moment of panic. Whilst they could see all the databases under the instance, any attempt to view information was met with an access denied prompt. On the database they did have access to, they were able to select/deselect any of the permissions against any user and not see any sort of prompt, whilst none of the selections remained.

Is it possible to 'grey' out all the options that they can't actually implement?

Comment: Not that I know of. This would be a setting of some sort in SSMS. But since they can't actually change the setting (and if they don't have permission they probably shouldn't be trying) why does it really matter?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, just adds confusion.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS is client program as any other program. It does not have any special status. Your user has permission to read system tables like sys.object, sys.server_principals etc. That is why SSMS can build treeview in Object Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

> MSSQL allows a user with limited permissions on a database to navigate
>   using SSMS on that database as if they were an admin. I.e. if they
>   have view permission on a database they can look at users, all options
>   to grant/deny are selectable, but of course nothing is committed to
>   the database.

Absolutely not true.

By default `public` server role is granted `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission, and the only thing that you are permitted to do when you are granted this permission is to `list` databases on server, i.e. do `select * from sys.databases` or "see" databases in `SSMS Object Explorer`. Only "see" means only to know `database names`. Any `login` other than member of `sysadmin` server role or `owner` of database (the only `login` that has `authorization` on database) that is not `mapped` to `database` cannot `access` database at all.

This means you cannot "see" nothing within this `database`.

> And they can look at users, all options to grant/deny are selectable

is not true at all, they just cannot "open" the node of database where they are not mapped (have `connect` to a database).

Besides, even if `login` has `connect` permission on a database and has no other `permission`, even if it can "open" database node, it will see in "users" only its own user.

So check twice the `permissions` of your "user with limited permissions on a database", you surely just did not see all its `permissions`.

You check `permissions` by impersonating the corresponding `login` this way:

```
use your_db;

execute as login = 'limited_login';

select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'server');
--CONNECT SQL
--VIEW ANY DATABASE

select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database');

revert;
```

The first set of permissions is `server level permissions` and if there is any `permission` other than `CONNECT SQL` and `VIEW ANY DATABASE` your `login` is not so "limited" as you think.

The second set lists `database level permissions`, and if you see smth like `view definition` this is the key of its "seeing users".

> Is it possible to 'grey' out all the options that they can't actually
>   implement?

Just revoke `view definition` to those `users`